# Is it physically realistic to have an electric field and polarisation density but no displacement field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

Given a Lagrangian density that describes a classical dielectric in interaction with the EM field, I found the Euler-Lagrange equations, and in the case of the electric field, worked through to find that $\vec{P} = -\epsilon_0 \vec{E}$. For some reason alarm bells are going off in my head but I'm not sure why. This implies from the usual equation $\vec{D} = \epsilon_0 \vec{E} + \vec{P}$ that the displacement field is zero. I suppose this just means that inside this dielectric the polarisation density exactly compensates $\epsilon_0 \vec{E}$, but I'm feeling unsure. Could somebody reassure (/correct!) me?

Comment: Is that not exactly the case in a classical perfect conductor?

Comment: you are saying you have a relative permittivity of zero? Typically relative permittivities are greater than one. I think a classical perfect conductor is the limit where the permittivity goes to infinity. I think something was probably wrong with your calculation where you got $\vec{P} = - \epsilon_0 \vec{E}$. You ought to have a property of the dielectric enter somewhere into that equation. Are you given its permittivity? If you are you should get $\vec{P} = (\epsilon -\epsilon_0) \vec{E}$ .

Comment: Ah you make a good point, yes as $\vec{D} = \epsilon \vec{E}$ if $\vec{D}$ is zero then the permittivity must be zero, which it isn't as I derived it earlier. Ok back to the start I suppose!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polarisation field is given by ${\bf P} = \chi_e \epsilon_0 {\bf E}$ in linear dielectric materials, where $\chi_e=\epsilon_r - 1$.

ie. the polarisation is defined to be *in the same direction* as the electric field.

Therefore the equation ${\bf D} = \epsilon_0 \epsilon_r {\bf E}$ is equivalent to ${\bf D} = \epsilon_0 (1+\chi_e) {\bf E} = \epsilon_0 {\bf E} + {\bf P}$.

So unless $\chi_e$, the dielectric susceptibility is negative, the electric field and polarisation field act in the same direction, so can't cancel. Such materials do exist (but I am no expert here), but I suspect you have just made a mistake in deriving the relationship between polarisation field and electric field.